# Here map loading issue when connected to wifi with no internet

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps

I am using here map sdk lite version to load map.
We have encountered 1 strange issue.
When we are connecting to WIFI with no internet, It is requesting to oauth2/token multiple times in background which result in hanging of UI.
Can you please suggest us a solution where we can stop this call in such scenario.
Or is it possible to execute it in background.

Below are logs:

2022-07-27 17:29:01.063 5605-5961/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug W/OLP: [WARN ] OLP - Request timed out, request_id=4, timeout=10, retry_count=0, url='https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token'
2022-07-27 17:29:01.065 5605-5961/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug E/Authentication: [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 3, Message: Network request timed out., HTTPStatusCode: -7)
2022-07-27 17:29:01.074 5605-6888/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2022-07-27 17:29:01.074 5605-6888/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2022-07-27 17:29:07.106 5605-6554/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/Logger63 -> i() -> Line: 83: toUINetworkDetails
2022-07-27 17:29:07.106 5605-6634/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/Logger63 -> i() -> Line: 83: toUINetworkDetails
2022-07-27 17:29:07.106 5605-6631/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/Logger63 -> i() -> Line: 83: toUINetworkDetails
2022-07-27 17:29:07.108 5605-6705/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug I/Logger63 -> i() -> Line: 83: toUINetworkDetails
2022-07-27 17:29:11.068 5605-5960/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug W/OLP: [WARN ] OLP - Request timed out, request_id=5, timeout=10, retry_count=0, url='https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token'
2022-07-27 17:29:11.070 5605-5960/com.daimler.android.sixtythree.debug E/Authentication: [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 3, Message: Network request timed out., HTTPStatusCode: -7)
2022-07-27 17:29:11.079 5605-6900/com

Comment: Try to check if you can reproduce this with the HelloMap example app from https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples. If you can reproduce it, I would suggest to contact the HERE support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear User, Please provide code snippet , so that we can check at our end.